# Arduino resets itself

Tags: arduino-uno

If I connect more power consuming components to Arduino, it gets reset. What is the cause of this observation?

Comment: Look up "brownout".  For example https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=246359.0

Comment: What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

When powered through USB there is a resettable polymeric ("poly") fuse. If you draw more than about 500mA this fuse will cut out and isolate the power.  When you remove the load the fuse will reset and allow power back to the board.

"Poly" fuses are in fact "Positive Temperature Coefficient" (PTC) thermistors. As they get hot their resistance increases (as opposed to the NTC thermistors you use for temperature sensing where the resistance decreases as they get hotter).  The current flowing through the PTC causes it to warm up. Too much current and it gets too hot, and the resistance gets too high (it's non-linear, so the resistance suddenly increases a lot).

Comment: Very good information!

Answer (score 1):

Branded Arduino boards have overload protection on their voltage regulators. If the voltage regulator overheats it shuts down, and then attempts to restart when the temperature returns to normal. I believe there is also short-circuit protection, although I'm not positive.

When power returns the processor will do a power-on reset.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on **what** is shorted. As stated by Duncan C, shorting the 5V pin to ground will probably not harm the arduino due to the mentioned protection mechanisms.
On the other hand an output port should not be shorted, chances are that the port gets destroyed.

In case of a short circuit the arduino "resets" itself because the voltage drops below the mcu's operating conditions, because the voltage regulator either shuts down completely or is not able to provide enough current.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this: An Arduino was not designed as a power supply. Connect your loads to an external power supply things will get a lot better.